# My program generates a yearly workout program in the variation of 5/3/1

Tags: java

I've been building this program for around a week or two on my spare time because I'm slowly starting to figure out how to code better. This program generates a yearly 5/3/1 cycle that is exported to a CSV file so you can easily print it off if you want.

Below is my code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package main;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * @author Brandon
 *
 */
public class Five31 {



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //initialize 1RM variables. Also generate arrays that are constant every month.
        double squat = 0, bench = 0, dl = 0, ohp = 0;
        double week1[] = {.65, .75, .85};
        double week2[] = {.70, .80, .90};
        double week3[] = {.75, .85, .95};
        double week4[] = {.40, .50, .60};
        welcome();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        exercisee a = new exercisee();
        //get user input and validate user responses.
        //validation by ensuring that user can't enter less than 45 lbs.
        System.out.println("What's your name?");
        String b = input.next();
        a.setName(b);
        System.out.println("Nice to meet you, " + a.getName());
        System.out.println("What's your max squat?");
        while(squat < 45){
            squat = input.nextDouble();
            if(squat < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
            }
        }
        squat = roundTo5(squat);
        a.setMaxSquat(squat);
        System.out.println("Your max squat is " + a.getMaxSquat());
        System.out.println("What's your max bench?");
        while(bench < 45) {
            bench = input.nextDouble();
            if (bench < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
            }
        }
        bench = roundTo5(bench);
        a.setMaxBench(bench);
        System.out.println("Your max bench is " + a.getMaxBench());
        System.out.println("What's your max deadlift?");
        while(dl < 45) {
            dl = input.nextDouble();
            if(dl < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
            }
        }
        dl = roundTo5(dl);
        a.setMaxDL(dl);
        System.out.println("Your max deadlift is " + a.getMaxDL());
        System.out.println("What's your max overhead press?");
        while(ohp < 45) {
            ohp = input.nextDouble();
            if(ohp < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
            }
        }
        ohp = roundTo5(ohp);
        a.setMaxOHP(ohp);
        System.out.println("Your max overhead press is " + a.getMaxOHP());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Calculating training maxes for the cycles...");
        System.out.println("");
        //declare training max variables and calculate training maxes.
        double tSquat=0, tBench = 0, tDL = 0, tOHP = 0;
        tSquat = (.9 * a.getMaxSquat());
        tBench = (.9 * a.getMaxBench());
        tDL = (.9 * a.getMaxDL());
        tOHP = (.9 * a.getMaxOHP());
        //round those calculations to the nearest 5 lbs and cast them into integers.
        tSquat = roundTo5(tSquat);
        tBench = roundTo5(tBench);
        tDL = roundTo5(tDL);
        tOHP = roundTo5(tOHP);
        //store values into array.
        double trainingMax[] = {tSquat, tBench, tDL, tOHP};
        String exerciseList[] = {"Squat", "Bench", "Deadlift", "Overhead Press"};
        //set training maxes for the object.
        a.setTrainingSquat(tSquat);
        a.setTrainingBench(tBench);
        a.setTrainingDL(tDL);
        a.setTrainingOHP(tOHP);
        //display training maxes for various exercises.
        System.out.println("Your training max for squat is " + a.getTSquat());
        System.out.println("Your training max for bench is " + a.getTBench());
        System.out.println("Your training max for deadlift is " + a.getTDL());
        System.out.println("Your training max for overhead press is " + a.getTOHP());
        System.out.println("");
        //Generate data for the month.
        System.out.println("Week 1 (3x5) at 65%, 75%, 85%");
        System.out.println("Week 2 (3x3) at 70%, 80%, 90%");
        System.out.println("Week 3 (1x5, 1x3, 1x1) at 75%, 85%, 95%");
        System.out.println("Week 4: Deload(Optional) 3x5 at 40%, 50%, 60%");
        System.out.println("");
        //need to have this for generating data for year. 
        String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "October", "November", "December"
        };
        //create buffered writer obj with filewriter object. allows use of newLine that buffered writer has.
        String csvFile = "/Users/Brandon/Desktop/results.csv";
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
        /* This loop can be confusing
         * the most confusing part is following it.
         * var i is used for months
         * if you follow i, at the bottom, this program automatically adjusts training maxes by 5 per week.
         * conservative, but fair. this will stop people from jumping into heavier workloads for no reason and potentially injuring themselves.
         * var l is used for weeks
         * var j is used for tracking exercise
         * var k is used for generating workout sets.
         */
        //Generates data for an entire year. 4 for loops. days + weeks + months + sets.
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        bw.write(months[i]);
        bw.write(",");
        bw.write("Exercise");
        bw.write(",");
        bw.write("Set 1");
        bw.write(",");
        bw.write("Set 2");
        bw.write(",");
        bw.write("Set 3");
        bw.newLine();
        //week
            for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
                bw.write("Week " + Integer.toString(l+1));
                System.out.println("Week " + (l+1) + ":");
                System.out.println("");
                if(l == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Easy week");
                }
                //
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    System.out.println((j+1) + " day: ("+exerciseList[j]+")");
                    bw.write(",");
                    bw.write(exerciseList[j]);
                    bw.write(",");
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Proposed sets: ");
                    //Generates weights for the exercises
                    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        if(l == 0) {
                            switch(j) {
                            case 0:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week1[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week1[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week1[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week1[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        System.out.println(roundTo5((week1[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                        }
                        else if(l == 1) {
                            switch(j) {
                            case 0:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        System.out.println(roundTo5((week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                        }
                        else if(l == 2) {
                            switch(j) {
                            case 0:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week3[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week3[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week3[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week3[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        System.out.println(roundTo5((week3[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                        }
                        else if(l == 3){
                            switch(j) {
                            case 0:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week4[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week4[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week4[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week4[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                                bw.write(",");
                                if(k == 2) {
                                    bw.newLine();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        System.out.println(roundTo5((week4[k] * trainingMax[j])));
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
                bw.newLine();
            }
            for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                trainingMax[c] = trainingMax[c] + 5;
            }
        }
        bw.close();
        exit();     
    }
    //this is necessary because there is no such thing as a 2.3 lb weight at the gym.
    //all weight numbers are integers, at least in my gym.

    public static int roundTo5(double t) {
        return (int) (5*(Math.round(t/5)));
    }


    public static void welcome() {
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("*                                         *");
        System.out.println("*     Welcome to the 5/3/1 calculator     *");
        System.out.println("*                                         *");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
    }

    public static void exit() {
        System.out.println("Thanks for using my program! -Brandon");
    }


}
```

I'm looking for any suggestions on how I could've improved it or what I did wrong because I thought I did a pretty good job, but I know this community is going to roast my entire code. I could have probably added a few try and catch statements in where the CSV file operation begins just to start off.

Edit: I just wanted to show you guys how the program looks in the CSV file as well. Less work for you guys.

[image: how it looks]

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of duplicated code here which makes your logic here more difficult than it needs to be.  As a first step, consider extracting some of the functionality into into reusable chunks.  For example:

A method:

```
private static double promptForMax(Scanner input, String activity) {
    double max = 0;
    System.out.println("What's your max " + activity + "?");
    while (max < 45) {
        max = input.nextDouble();
        if (max < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
        }
    }
    max = roundTo5(max);
    return max;
}
```

Could be reused for each of the activity inputs.  By removing the unnecessary temporary variables, the input fetching would then look more like:

```
a.setMaxSquat(promptForMax(input, "squat"));
System.out.println("Your max squat is " + a.getMaxSquat());
a.setMaxBench(promptForMax(input, "bench"));
System.out.println("Your max bench is " + a.getMaxBench());
a.setMaxDL(promptForMax( input, "deadlift"));
System.out.println("Your max deadlift is " + a.getMaxDL());
a.setMaxOHP(promptForMax(input, "overhead press"));
System.out.println("Your max overhead press is " + a.getMaxOHP());
```

Which is a lot more concise.

There's other sections where you seem to be executing exactly the same code for different values.  Consider this `switch`:

> ```
> switch (j) {
>     case 0:
>         bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
>         bw.write(",");
>         if (k == 2) {
>             bw.newLine();
>         }
>         break;
>     case 1:
>         bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
>         bw.write(",");
>         if (k == 2) {
>             bw.newLine();
>         }
>         break;
>     case 2:
>         bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
>         bw.write(",");
>         if (k == 2) {
>             bw.newLine();
>         }
>         break;
>     case 3:
>         bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
>         bw.write(",");
>         if (k == 2) {
>             bw.newLine();
>         }
>         break;
> ```

Every `case` does the same exact thing.  It seems like it's the equivalent of:

```
if(j >= 0 && j <= 3) {
    bw.write(Integer.toString(roundTo5(week2[k] * trainingMax[j])));
    bw.write(",");
    if (k == 2) {
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

You do the same thing for week3.  Reducing this duplication, through extracting meaningfully named methods, looking for different branching logic / variable, will go a long way to making the program more approachable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains a lot of duplicate code and is hard to read.

In this code, I tried to get rid of duplicated code. I got rid of the object "exercisee" that is unnecessary in my opinion.
Got rid of a lot of nesting in methods. And he made sure that all the information was first collected in the StringBuilder and then completely displayed in the csv file.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 /**
  * @author Brandon
  *
  */
public class Five31 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    welcome();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What's your name?");
    String youName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Nice to meet you, " + youName);

    double squat =  issue( input, "squat" );
    double trainingSquat = calc( squat );
    double bench = issue( input, "bench" );
    double trainingBench = calc( bench);
    double deadlift = issue( input, "deadlift" );
    double trainingDeadlift =  calc( deadlift );
    double ohp = issue( input, "overhead press" );
    double trainingOPH = calc( ohp );


    double[] trainingMax = {trainingSquat, trainingBench,trainingDeadlift,trainingOPH};

    System.out.println("Report file path?");
    String reportFilePath = input.next();

    printToCsv( createReport( trainingMax ), reportFilePath );

    exit();
}


private static StringBuilder createReport(double[] trainingMax){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    iteratorMonths(sb, trainingMax);
    return sb;
}


public static int roundTo5(double t) {
    return (int) (5*(Math.round(t/5)));
}


public static void welcome() {
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("*                                         *");
    System.out.println("*     Welcome to the 5/3/1 calculator     *");
    System.out.println("*                                         *");
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
}

public static void exit() {
    System.out.println("Thanks for using my program! -Brandon");
}



private static double issue( Scanner input, String p ){
    System.out.println("What's your max " + p + "?");
    double val;
    do{
        val =  input.nextDouble();
        if(val < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
        }
    }while(val < 45);
    val = roundTo5(val);
    System.out.println("Your max " + p + " is " + val);
    return val;
}

private static double calc(double val){
    return roundTo5(0.9 * val);
}

private static void printToCsv( StringBuilder sb, String filePath){
    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(filePath) ) ){

        bw.write( sb.toString() );
    }catch( IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private static void iteratorMonths( StringBuilder sb, double[] trainingMax){

    String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                       "June", "July", "August",
                       "September", "October", "November", "December"
    };


    for( String month : months ){
        sb.append( month ).append( ",Exercise,Set 1,Set 2,Set 3\r\n" );
        iteratorWeeks( sb, trainingMax );
        trainingMaxPlus( trainingMax );
    }
}


private static void trainingMaxPlus( double[] trainingMax ){
    for( int i = 0; i < trainingMax.length; i++ ){
        trainingMax[i] = trainingMax[i] + 5;
    }
}


private static void iteratorWeeks( StringBuilder sb, double[] trainingMax){

    double[][] weeksKoeffs={
        {.65, .75, .85},
        {.70, .80, .90},
        {.75, .85, .95},
        {.40, .50, .60}
    };

    for( int i = 1; i <= weeksKoeffs.length; i++ ){
        sb.append( "Week ").append( i );
        System.out.println( "Week " + i + ":\r\n" );
        if( i == weeksKoeffs.length ){
            System.out.println( "Easy week" );
        }
        iteratorDays(sb, weeksKoeffs[i-1], trainingMax);
        System.out.println();
        sb.append( "\r\n" );
    }
}


private static void iteratorDays( StringBuilder sb, double[] weekKoeffs, double[] trainingMax){
    String[] exerciseList = { "Squat", "Bench", "Deadlift", "Overhead Press"};
    String exercise;
    for( int j = 0; j < exerciseList.length; j++ ){
        exercise = exerciseList[j];
        System.out.println( ( j + 1 ) + " day: (" + exercise + ")" );
        sb.append(",").append( exercise).append( "," );
        System.out.println();
        iteratorProposedSets(sb, weekKoeffs, trainingMax[j]);
        sb.append( "\r\n" );
    }
}


private static void iteratorProposedSets( StringBuilder sb, double[] weekKoeffs, double trainingMax){
    System.out.println( "Proposed sets: " );
    for( double weekKoeff : weekKoeffs ){
        iteratorProposedSet( sb, weekKoeff, trainingMax );

    }
}


private static void iteratorProposedSet( StringBuilder sb, double weekKoeff, double trainingMax){
    int val = roundTo5( weekKoeff * trainingMax );
    sb.append( val).append( "," );
    System.out.println(val);
}

}
```

Comment: You present a lot of code. Can you please argue how changes are an improvement, or is *duplicate code and hard to read* the gist of it? Does it add insight about the code presented in the question beyond [forsvarir's review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236281/93149)?

Comment: In this code, I tried to get rid of duplicated code. I got rid of the object "exercisee" that is unnecessary in my opinion. Got rid of a lot of nesting in methods. And he made sure that all the information was first collected in the StringBuilder and then completely displayed in the csv file.

Answer (score 2):

It seems clear that you haven't split up the functionality in methods. That makes the code hard to maintain, more error prone, more likely to contain duplicate code fragments.

It is very clear that you mix input / output and functionality: the calculations. Those are normally split into separate classes. Classes should be relatively small, maybe a hundred lines max; some persons even like much smaller classes than that - but it is possible to overdo it, in my opinion.

The architecture is already addressed, so I'll just talk about the code / Java specific issues that I see:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package main;
```

That's not a good name for a package at all. Use a reversed web address or at least something that reflects the contents of the code.

The JavaDoc comment should not be there at all (you can create your own `package-info.java` if you want to document the package; we cannot have classes within the package redefine the package description after all.

```
public class Five31 {
```

That's a good name if the rest of the community understands it. However, if the class only contains static methods then the class should be `final` and there should be a private zero argument constructor to avoid instantiation.

```
    /**
     * @param args
     */
```

Either remove it, put a TODO in it or describe it, but don't leave it hanging.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

Maybe your users won't be all that happy to have to deal with `IOException` themselves.

```
        //initialize 1RM variables. Also generate arrays that are constant every month.
```

1RM, oh, right. Why not use full words? Same for your variable definitions. Not everybody will get these acronyms. Expect programmers, not athletes.

```
        double squat = 0, bench = 0, dl = 0, ohp = 0;
```

Variable definitions should be defined where they occur in Java, and they should not be filled with default values such as `0`. A compiler error is better than forgetting to assign them a value after all.

```
        double week1[] = {.65, .75, .85};
        ...
```

These should be defined as `private static final double[] WEEK1 = {.65, .75, .85}`, the Java equivalent of constant values. In Java, prefer to put the brackets after the type, so that it is clear that the type is `double[]`.

```
        welcome();
```

Thank you, but what about `printWelcome`?

```
        exercisee a = new exercisee();
```

Bad class name, should start with an uppercase character. And the excercisee should probably have some defining characteristics (such as a name or ID) right from the start? And calling the excercisee `a` is just lazy. I'd expect something like `Exercisee exercisee = new Exercisee(name);`.

```
        while(squat < 45){
            squat = input.nextDouble();
            if(squat < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please input a value greater than 45 lbs.");
            }
        }
```

Now the `if` statement looks for values `< 1` and the `while` looks for values `< 45`. That's weird, isn't it? And note that you are now assigning the value already; you can simply put `double squat` right in front of the `while` loop and everything will run fine.

```
        squat = roundTo5(squat);
```

If you would retrieve `squat` in a function `double maxSquat = retrieveMaxSquat()` then you'd just have a single line left, and squat would not have to be assigned a value multiple times.

```
        System.out.println("Calculating training maxes for the cycles...");
```

Are you expecting this to take weeks?

```
        double tSquat=0, tBench = 0, tDL = 0, tOHP = 0;
```

Ah, forgetting to call it `maxSquat` is biting you now, right? Same as before, declare variables where they are needed.

```
        tSquat = (.9 * a.getMaxSquat());
```

Ah, `0.9`, the ultimate magic value. This should be constant (`private static final double SOMETHING = 0.9`).

---

... uh, now I ran out of time and steam, there is plenty that can be enhanced, but it would take another day for me to pick this apart. Maybe I'll refactor later.

Comment: Added an answer where I refactored...

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's do the ultimate refactoring to classes. Beware that there won't be much left of the original code, but your ideas are of course still in there.

Start with `package-info.java` (I called the package `pressing`) as you can see:

```
/**
 * This is the package for FiveThreeOne, an application to calculate training exercises given your maximum
 * weight for a specific exercise.
 */
package com.stackexchange.codereview.pressing;
```

The other files that I show are in that package, under `<classname>.java`.

Here is what is left of your main `Five31` class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class FiveThreeOne {

    /**
     * Performs the FiveThreeOne operation for a specific person.
     * 
     * @param args no arguments required
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        var calc = new TrainingCalculator();

        var console = new ConsoleUI(System.in, System.out, calc);
        console.printWelcome();

        var name = console.requestName();
        var gymnast = new Gymnast(name);

        for (Exercise exercise : Exercise.values()) {
            int max = console.requestMax(exercise);
            gymnast.setMax(exercise, max);
        }

        // DEBUG print out exercisee using Exercisee.toString()
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(gymnast);
        // and some training maximum stuff
        System.out.printf("Max training for squat: %d%n", calc.calculateTrainingMaximum(gymnast.getMax(Exercise.SQUAT).getAsInt()));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Results are being written to file %s.csv...%n", name);
        System.out.println();

        // want it on the screen instead? Pass System.out to TrainingCreator as first argument!
        try (PrintStream bw = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(name + ".csv"))) {
            var creator = new TrainingCreator(bw, calc);
            creator.createTraining(gymnast);
        }

        console.printGoodbye();
    }

}
```

Then there is the `Exercise` enum:

```
public enum Exercise {
    SQUAT, BENCH, DEADLIFT;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

the `Gymnast` class, which replaces the `exercisee` class, as I generally keep to words defined in the dictionary...

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.OptionalInt;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public final class Gymnast {
    // no setter for name to avoid confusion, use a static ID otherwise
    private String name;

    // the tree-based map keeps the keys (i.e. exercises) in order
    private Map<Exercise, Integer> maxForExercises = new TreeMap<>();

    public Gymnast(String name) {
        // guard to avoid invalid state
        if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
        }

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setMax(Exercise exercise, int max) {
        maxForExercises.put(exercise, max);
    }

    public Set<Exercise> getExercises() {
        return maxForExercises.keySet();
    }

    public OptionalInt getMax(Exercise exercise) {
        return OptionalInt.of(maxForExercises.get(exercise));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Gymnast)) {
            return false;
        }

        final Gymnast that = (Gymnast) obj;
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase(that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s", name, maxForExercises);
    }
}
```

The all important `TrainingCalculator` contains your calculations:

```
public final class TrainingCalculator {
    private static final int MINIMUM_WEIGHT = 45;
    private static final double MAX_TO_TRAINING_MAX_COEFFICIENT = 0.9;
    private static final int ADJUSTMENT_TO_TRAINING_MAXIMUM = 5;
    private static double WEEKLY_EFFORT[][] = {{ .65, .75, .85 }, { .70, .80, .90 }, { .75, .85, .95 },
            { .40, .50, .60 } };

    public TrainingCalculator() {
        // actually auto-generated by Java, but I prefer it being there
    }

    /**
     * This automatically adjusts training maximums by 5 per week which is
     * conservative, but fair.
     * This will stop people from jumping into heavier
     * workloads for no reason and potentially injuring themselves.
     * 
     * @param trainingMax an array of training maximums to be adjusted
     */
    public void adjustTrainingMaximum(int[] trainingMax) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trainingMax.length; i++) {
            trainingMax[i] = trainingMax[i] + ADJUSTMENT_TO_TRAINING_MAXIMUM;
        }
    }

    public int calculateTrainingForSet(int week, int workoutSet, int maxTraining) {
        return roundTo5(WEEKLY_EFFORT[week - 1][workoutSet] * maxTraining);
    }

    public int calculateTrainingMaximum(int max) {
        return roundTo5(MAX_TO_TRAINING_MAX_COEFFICIENT * max);
    }

    /**
     * This method is necessary because there is no such thing as a 2.3 lb weight at the
     * gym;
     * All weight numbers are integers, at least in my gym.
     * 
     * @param weight the weight to round
     * @return the weight rounded to the closest multiple of 5 as integer
     */
    public int roundTo5(double weight) {
        return 5 * (int) (Math.round((double) weight / 5));
    }

    public boolean hasMinimumWeight(int max) {
        return max >= MINIMUM_WEIGHT;
    }
}
```

Then come the I/O classes, starting with the UI class, now split from the calculation and output functionality:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleUI {

    private Scanner scanner;
    private PrintStream out;
    private TrainingCalculator calc;

    public ConsoleUI(InputStream in, PrintStream out, TrainingCalculator calc) {
        this.out = out;
        this.scanner = new Scanner(in);
        this.calc = calc;
    }

    public void printWelcome() {
        out.println("*******************************************");
        out.println("*                                         *");
        out.println("*     Welcome to the 5/3/1 calculator     *");
        out.println("*                                         *");
        out.println("*******************************************");
        out.println();
    }

    public String requestName() {
        out.println("What's your name?");
        var name = scanner.next();
        out.printf("Nice to meet you, %s!%n", name);
        out.println();
        return name;
    }

    public int requestMax(Exercise exercise) {
        int max;
        while (true) {
            out.printf("What's your max for %s?%n", exercise);
            int inputMaxSquat = scanner.nextInt();
            max = calc.roundTo5(inputMaxSquat);
            if (calc.hasMinimumWeight(max)) {
                break;
            }

            out.println("Input a value greater than 45 (values in lbs) - please try again.");
        }
        out.printf("Your max for %s is (rounded to multiples of five): %d%n", exercise, max);
        out.println();
        return max;
    }

    public void printGoodbye() {
        // we need symmetry, so box the goodbye!
        out.println("*******************************************");
        out.println("*                                         *");
        out.println("* Thanks for using my program!  - Brandon *");
        out.println("*                                         *");
        out.println("*******************************************");
    }

}
```

and finally, the `TrainingCreator` creates your CSV output:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TrainingCreator {
    private static int WEEK_COUNT = 4;
    private static final int WORKOUT_SETS = 3;

    private PrintStream out;
    private TrainingCalculator calc;

    public TrainingCreator(PrintStream out, TrainingCalculator calc) {
        this.out = out;
        this.calc = calc;
    }

    public void createTraining(Gymnast gymnast) {
        int[] trainingMax = new int[gymnast.getExercises().size()];
        int exerciseIndex = 0;
        for (Exercise exercise : gymnast.getExercises()) {
            trainingMax[exerciseIndex++] = calc.calculateTrainingMaximum(gymnast.getMax(exercise).getAsInt());
        }

        // generates data for an entire year: days + weeks + months + sets
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
            writeHeaderForMonth(month, 3);
            for (int week = 1; week <= WEEK_COUNT; week++) {
                writeWeek(gymnast, week, trainingMax);
            }
            out.println();

            calc.adjustTrainingMaximum(trainingMax);
        }
    }

    private void writeHeaderForMonth(int month, int sets) {
        String monthStr = Month.of(month).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.US);
        out.print(monthStr);
        out.print(",");
        out.print("Exercise");
        for (int set = 0; set < sets; set++) {
            out.printf(", Set %d", set);
        }
        out.println();
    }

    private void writeWeek(Gymnast gymnast, int week, int[] trainingMax) {
        out.printf("Week %d", week);
        for (Exercise exercise : gymnast.getExercises() ) {
            out.print(",");
            writeExersize(week, exercise, trainingMax);
        }
    }

    private void writeExersize(int week, Exercise exercise, int[] trainingMax) {
        out.print(capitalize(exercise.toString()));
        out.print(",");
        // Generates weights for the exercises
        int maxTraining = trainingMax[exercise.ordinal()];
        for (int workoutSet = 0; workoutSet < WORKOUT_SETS; workoutSet++) {
            int training = calc.calculateTrainingForSet(week, workoutSet, maxTraining);
            out.print(Integer.toString(training));
            if (workoutSet < WORKOUT_SETS -1) {
                out.print(",");
            } else {
                out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    private String capitalize(String name) {
        return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Now if you run this all then you should get about what you created yourself - the CSV output should not differ. However, I do print less to screen. The problem is that putting `System.out.println` statement all through the code gets messy fast. Rather than doing that you can copy `TrainingCreator` to `TrainingCreatorForConsole` or something and then make the necessary changes. Then you can just run both...

Adding any exercises or changing the calculations should be uber-simple with this class design. Actually, one exercise is missing: try and add it to the enum, and you'll understand the strength of a well thought out class design.

Personally, I would try and get the `TrainingCreator` to output a `TrainingTable` representing the data now in the CSV. Then you can convert that data to both the CSV file and an onscreen text. However, that is certainly still a lot of work, and figuring out the design of the table is pretty tough (but doable). Probably not entirely worth it for this standalone application.

Comment: And I thought "exercise" was written incorrectly. Oh well, refactor at will..

Comment: Most of your fields can be final, you might want to update them for consistency.  Is there any particular reason why you've overridden `equals` and `hashCode`? At first glance, it seems like these aren't needed/used.

Comment: @forsvarir I took name as the main identifier, by a lack of better. I generally implement these for data classes with setters, because they tend to get stored into lists and whatnot (in iteration x of the program).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: you could build the month array using

```java
String[] months = Stream.of(Month.values()).map(month->month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)).toArray(String[]::new)
```

This allows you to control the way months are displayed (like using a different `TextStyle` for abbreviated names, or changing the language). Not a big improvement for your program, but it ensures you don't make any typo.